# NV12 Format Image Show in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I got image pixel from the IoT camera and used **SoftwareBitmap** class to store my **NV12** pixel buffer data.

**But the SoftwareBitmap displayed in a XAML app must be in BGRA pixel format with pre-multiplied alpha values.**

Do I have to **convert NV12 to BGRA**?

How can I directly show NV12 Or BGR24 pixel format in UWP C# Code？

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to convert NV12 to BGRA?

Yes. UWP doesn't support displaying NV12 format image directly. You would have to convert it.

I saw that Xin has submitted a [feature request](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/20244928-uwp-image-control-and-bitmapsource) on UWP User Voice. You could vote it up. MS might think about adding this feature in the later version base on the energy value for this feature request.

Comment: Oh...that's me.